# Standard model in curved spacetime

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, qft-in-curved-spacetime

What is the effective lagrangian for the standard model in an arbitrary spacetime background?

Answer (score 6):

The generalization of the standard model is done the same way as all other generalizations to general relativity, although with spinors to treat carefully.

Scalar and vector fields must have their derivatives replaced with the covariant derivative

$$\partial_\mu \varphi(x) \to \nabla_\mu \varphi(x)$$

Inner products are replaced with the adequate metric

$$A^\mu A_\mu \to g_{\mu\nu} A^\mu A^\nu$$

For spinors, be careful to use the spin connection and tetrad fields

$$\partial_\mu \psi\to \nabla _{\mu }\psi =(\partial _{\mu }-{i \over 4}\omega _{\mu }^{ab}\sigma _{ab})\psi $$

$$\gamma^\mu \to e^{\mu}_a \gamma^a$$

Also it should be noted that you can add various terms coupling the field to the curvature, such as the scalar coupling $\xi \varphi R$.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing? All of it?! With all the i's dotted and t's crossed? Gravity too, meaning the General Relativity stuff - the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian density? Ok. Let's make it simple (relatively speaking) and interesting

> [The Standard Model Lagrangian In Detail With Gravity Included](https://www.scribd.com/document/381875855/Standard-Model-Lagrangian-in-Detail-with-Gravity-Included)

By the way, don't rely on [Symmetry Magazine's Rendition Of The Standard Model Lagrangian](https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/the-deconstructed-standard-model-equation?language_content_entity=und). Besides being for flat space, it has errors, e.g. the term on line 15 of that monstrosity that starts "$\frac12 g \frac1{c_w} (Z_μ^0 (H⋯) ⋯\color{red}{)}$" has unbalanced parentheses and is missing the "$\color{red}{)}$". So, it's not been properly validated, even though it's a widespread meme.

Time permitting, I'll upgrade, re-validate and move the Scribd PDF over here, if it fits the space requirements or else on GitHub (or both); because some time ago Scribd pulled a bait and switch and semi-garden-walled everything. It's still accessible, but ad-walled.

One of the "dot-i's and cross-t's" talking points is to not forget the $\sqrt{|g|}$ in the Lagrangian density. That's not just needed for curved background backgrounds, but *also* for Minkowski geometries in curvilinear (and/or non-inertial, e.g. lab) coordinates. The same, actually, goes for the metric and connection coefficients. The extra $\sqrt{|g|}$ factor for the Lagrangian density is alluded to in part 4, pages 22-26. So, all references to "Lagrangian" preceding that can be considered to be to the de-densitized Lagrangian density (which is tacitly the common practice), obtained by dividing out the extra factor.

The one thing you will notice is that there is no direct interaction with the metric. Instead, the only role the metric plays is to condition the quadratic terms in the Lagrangian density. It creates the background causal structure of the underlying geometry, which shapes the light cones and tells you how waves propagate. Instead, the interaction occurs with the connection - as if it too were a gauge field. Effectively, it's the gauge field for the Lorentz group $SO(3,1)$ or its spinorized version $SL(2,ℂ)$. So, you just stick it in for the fermions with the isospin, hypercharge and color gauge fields, as if it were just another gauge field. The reason it's not called "Yang-Mills" is because the "kinetic terms" are linear, not quadratic. However, you *can* make them quadratic - like Yang-Mills - if the cosmological coefficient is non-zero. So, then it actually *would* become some kind of Yang-Mills field.

There are also de facto metric coefficients wherever else quadratic combinations occur - and they rarely ever treated correctly in the literature. The gauge field has a metric, which is always assumed to be adjoint-invariant. For the electromagnetism part of it, that metric reduces to a single coefficient $ε_0 c$. The fermion field *also* has a metric! For [The QED Lagrangian, Fully Written Out](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755822/what-is-the-full-qed-lagrangian-with-physics-units-written-out/783867#783867), I slipped a fermion metric in at the end as $ϝ_0$ (just to have an excuse to use Archaic Greek). The extra metric coefficients tacked on - as shown there - serve as a base for the renormalization of the Lagrangian, here this corresponds to $ϝ_0 → Z_1 ϝ_R = Z_2 ϝ_R$. Renormalization should be treated as something to be done on the coefficients, not on the fields.

So, in all, what you need is: (1) throw in the potentials for an $SL(2,ℂ)$ field in the $A$ field of the fermion $\bar{ψ} A ψ$ part of the Lagrangian, (2) make the metric coefficients explicit, e.g. $g^{μρ}g^{νσ}F_{μν}F_{ρσ}$ in all the places where space-time indices are contracted, (3) decompose the metric as $g_{μν} = η_{ab}h^a_μh^b_ν$, where $η_{ab}$ is a fixed Minkowski metric, and associate with them the frame one-forms $θ^a = h^a_μ dx^μ$ - that's necessary for the fermions, because the index in the gamma's is actually a frame index, not a coordinate index (e.g. $γ^a$, not $γ^μ$) ... which is why field theories with spinors need frame coefficients, rather than metric coefficients, (4) add in the $\sqrt{|g|}$ factor to the Lagrangian density (after decomposition, assuming the determinant of $\det(η) = 1$, that's already taken care of by using $θ^0 ∧ θ^1 ∧ ⋯ ∧ θ^{n-1}$ in place of $d^nx$ for the volume $n$-form in the action integral), (5) add in the Einstein-Cartan Lagrangian density for the $SL(2,ℂ)$ field and frame field, (6) optionally constrain torsion (i.e. the gauge-covariant derivative of the $θ^a$ fields) to be zero by, by making the Einstein-Cartan Lagrangian density the Palatini Lagrangian density, instead. That's effectively Einstein-Cartan plus extra terms that implement the zero torsion constraint. In the write-up linked above, Palatini isn't even mentioned. It's just taken for granted that it's Einstein-Cartan - because it's easier to write down.

You'll also find a detailed account of how to add in the gravitational sector in Chapter 21 of the latest accessible (2022) edition of the [Particle Data Group's handbook](https://pdg.lbl.gov/rpp-archive/index.html). Time permitting, I will lay out a Rosetta stone of their Lagrangian (and other Lagrangians seen on the net) with the one cited in the first link, either in an edit or second reply.